# Revtex 4.1 \cite{*[][]} command appends to previous Bibtex entry

Tags: bibtex, revtex

The [Revtex 4.1 Author's Guide](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf) (Sec. VIII.6) describes a new `\cite{*[{PrependText}][{AppendText}]BibtexKey}` command that inserts user-defined text around the citation. However, for me, star/asterisk in `\cite{*...}` also has the side-effect of appending the new bibitem to the end of the previous one. How can I fix this to get an independently numbered bibitem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new `\cite{}` command also works without the star/asterisk `*` (unlike what is suggested in the Author's Guide). The problem is solved by using the syntax:

```
\cite{[{PrependText}][{AppendText}]BibtexKey}
```

This requires the latest version of natbib and the bst files that come with Revtex 4.1. An error may indicate the necessity of upgrading to the 2016 version of TeX Live or MacTex.